# NotMapped Error in EF5 and .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, code-first, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

In VS2012(.NET 4.5  and Entity Framework 5 )

When exposed the inheritance relationship，caused the compile-time errors:

> You cannot use Ignore method on the property 'InnerString' on type
>   'MrTree.SubSubClass' because this type inherits from the type
>   'MrTree.BaseClass' where this property is mapped. To exclude this
>   property from your model, use NotMappedAttribute or Ignore method on
>   the base type.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDbcontext db = new MyDbcontext();
            int i = db.SubSubClasses.Count();
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public string InnerString { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubClass : BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class SubSubClass : SubClass
    {
    }

    public class MyDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SubSubClass> SubSubClasses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubClass> SubClasses { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around for this issue I have experienced myself. I did post some supplementary information about what might be causing the issue but it was deleted by some egotistical nerd who felt it wasn't worthy.
So here is my ANSWER to this problem - might not be entirely right but it works for me so please don't delete this Mr Nerd just in case it helps out someone else.

Firstly, this issue only affects classes that do not inherit the abstract class using the NotMapped attribute directly but instead those that inherit from another class that itself inherits from the base class, as per the original statement.

The following works for me using something similar to the following class setup:

BASE CLASS:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; } // this will be mapped
   public virtual int DoNotMap { get; set; } // this should be ignored   
}
```

FIRST LEVEL INHERITANCE

```
public class Contact : EntityBase
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SECOND LEVEL INHERITANCE

```
public class Employee : Contact
{
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create a generic configuration class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
public class DataEntityBaseConfiguration<T> 
  : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : EntityBase
{
  public DataEntityBaseConfiguration()
  {
    Ignore(x => x.DoNotMap);
  }
}
```

Create configuration classes for all first level inheritance that inherit directly from the EntityBase class, i.e.:

```
public class ContactConfiguration : DataEntityBaseConfiguration<Contact>
{
   // place any further configuration rules in the constructor
}
```

WORKAROUND: any classes that inherit from the EntityBase *indirectly*, simply create a Configuration class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
  // place any further configuration rules in the constructor
}
```

In your DataContext, in the OnModelCreating method, add you configurations:

modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactConfiguration());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeConfiguration());

Assuming a TPT approach in this instance, map the specialised version, Employee to its own table with an FK relation to Contact:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Map<Employee>(m => m.ToTable("Employees"));
```

This, for me at least, creates a contact table without the "DoNotMap" property and an Employee table without the "DoNotMap" table and with a PK/FK relation to Contact. Even though I do not inherit from the EntityBaseConfiguration for Employee Configuration, it still, somehow, picks up Ignore and leaves it out.
I would assume that if we went with a TPH approach, we would simply end up with a single Contact table plus Discriminator column. TPC would obviously recreate all the Contact properties in the Employee table but I'm not sure if it would also create the DoNotMap property - will test that when I have a moment spare.

In short, going back to the original question, I'm not sure why this happens with both the NotMapped attribute and the Ignore. I was getting the error when my EmployeeConfiguration inherited from the EntityBaseConfiguration. I'm not keen on the workaround as it firstly the error is false in its statement and secondly, it's a an error that would easy to fall into again, even if the solution is now quite simple.

Hope that helps anyone that has struggled with this inheritance issue.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the primary key has to be included in the POCO class definition A already means that Ais not a POCO object.  You cannot ignore properties on  POCO objects

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a property called `InnerString` in your `SubSubClass`?  That's what the error is saying, although you don't have it listed in your example code.

Your code above worked for me, but I had to add a PK, here's the entire Console app:

```
   public class BaseClass
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [NotMapped]
      public string InnerString { get; set; }
   }

   public class SubClass : BaseClass
   {
   }

   public class SubSubClass : SubClass
   {
   }

   public class MyDbcontext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<SubSubClass> SubSubClasses { get; set; }
      public DbSet<SubClass> SubClasses { get; set; }
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main( string[] args )
      {
         var context = new MyDbcontext();

         context.SubSubClasses.Add(new SubSubClass());
         context.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
```

And the database it created:

[image]

Comment: I offer about class definition of the code is complete. My development environment is Visual Studio 2012, Entity Framework 5.0.0, target framework is the.net Framework 4.5.50709, are you?

Comment: Yes, it's the same setup.  Did you add the Primary Key like i did?